# Use part of filename as variable bash

Tags: bash

Background:
I have a bunch of filenames named username.sub in single letter directories under script_testing (first letter of username is the folder name). For every username.sub, I need to check if the line user.$username.contacts exists and, if not, append the line followed by a real tab.

Question:
Given the code I have below, why is it not appending to the file? I think I am missing something simple. I keep getting "contacts already subscribed" even if that line is not there.

```
#!/bin/bash
 Path_to_files=/home/user/script_testing/^[A-z]+$/
 FULLNAME="${Path_to_files##*/}"
 NAME="${FULLNAME%.*}"
 if grep 'contacts' $NAME.sub; then
   echo 'contacts already subscribed'
else
    echo "subscribing to contacts"
    echo -e user.$NAME.Contacts \t >> $NAME.sub
fi
```

Comment: Can the file `username.sub` have more than one lines with `contacts` in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#testing directory
#p=$HOME/script_testing
for f in "$p"/*/*.sub ; do
# if this is a file
 if [ -f "$f" ]; then
# define variables
F="${f##*/}"
u="${F%%.*}"
cont=$(grep "user.$u.Contacts" "$f")
cal=$(grep "user.$u.Calendar" "$f")
# if our file doesn't contain Contacts subscription
if [ -z "$cont" ]; then
 # add Contacts subscription
 echo -e "user.$u.Contacts\t" >> "$f"
#fi
# if our file doesn't contain Calendar subscription
elif [ -z "$cal" ]; then
 # add Calendar subscription
 echo -e "user.$u.Calendar\t" >> "$f"
fi
fi
done
```

Also added extra line(s) to append. Please, let me know if there is an issue with this so I can learn, but I haven't encountered any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're grepping for the word `contacts` - which, depending on what else you have in those files, may always be present.

Instead, use `grep -q "^user\.$NAME\.Contacts"` to look for your line.

Comment: Granted, that was overlooked. On my test file, there is only 1 other line - `user.$NAME.folder`  Now I am getting the expected echo response, but nothing is actually being written to the file

Comment: If you're getting "subscribing to contacts" but nothing is added to the file, you probably don't have write permission to it. Also, I'd recommend double quoting the argument to echo, so your `\t` doesn't get lost on the way.

Comment: I feel like I'm looking for something right in front of my face and can't find it. I am now getting "contacts already subscribed" no matter what, and the file is not being written to. I do have write permissions. As it stands now, I made the suggested changes and I eliminated the regex in line 2 just in case I had it wrong. Testing on a single file now - which, if I hardcode everything in w/out variables, works fine.

Comment: @user2472122: Suggest you look at $?, which for grep returns 2 if it can't open the file, and 1 if it can't find a match.

Comment: I'm a dork. It is creating/appending to a file in the same directory as the script instead of the directory where the username.sub files are. I will have to figure out those adjustments now